# Azure Monitor Workbooks template

Tags: azure, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm trying to create a new custom template for Azure Monitor Workbooks, but I couldn't find a way from Azure Portal and I was also unable to find the documentation explaining steps to create a new template.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently have a way to do this from the Portal UI.  Its on the todo list, but most teams that use templates that way were already doing it programmatically via ARM templates so it isn't high on our list.

The documentation for how to do it via templates is here in [azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-automate#azure-resource-manager-template-for-deploying-a-workbook-instance)
(I'd paste the content here, but it is a LOT of details and then it would be out of date in two places?)